# SCSS sticky element covers child

Tags: html, css, sass, position, sticky

The wrapper displays on the top of the first parent element. Good!

The problem:
However the second parent element is on the top of the wrapper element, and I can't figure it out why. It needed behind the child element like the first parent. (In real life it's a modal, but I tried to simplify the problem.)

The parent element is sticky (and I can't change it.)
The wrapper element must be an absolute position element.

I've tried to change z-indexes, add extra wrappers, asked openAI, with no luck.

Basically it looks like this (scss):

```
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: -1;
  position: sticky; // <-must be sticky
 
  .wrap {
    position: absolute; // <-must be absolute
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 50px;
    height: 210px;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
 </div>
<div class="parent"></div>
```

To see in live the simplified problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-parent-sp3v3b?file=/src/styles.scss

The second blue box need to be behind the red as well.
Any advice would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the solution was it needed to add different indexes to the parent element like this:

```
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  border: 1px solid white; // <-must be sticky
  &:first-of-type {
    z-index: 1;
    }
    &:last-of-type {
    z-index: -1;
    }
```